# convert US dates to UK

Tags: python

In python is there a better way to convert from a US date format to a UK date format?

I am using the below:

```
df = ['01/31/2014', '02/06/2013']

for a in df:
    s = list(a)
    d = [s[3],s[4],s[2],s[0],s[1],s[5],s[6],s[7],s[8],s[9]]
    f.append("".join(d))

print (f)

['31/01/2014', '06/02/2013']
```

Comment: Define *better*. More readable, more efficient, more reliable?

Answer (score 5):

Use this instead,

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(your_date, '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: Sorry, I have edited it now.

Comment: This does not work with a four digit year as in the example of the OP. You have to use a capital Y like

    '%m/%d/%Y'

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one liner:

```
from datetime import datetime

df = ['01/31/2014', '02/06/2013']    
f = [datetime.strptime(d, "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%d/%m/%Y") for d in df]
print(f)
```

prints

```
['31/01/2014', '06/02/2013']
```

Comment: great thanks. exceptionaly useful

Answer (score 1):

Turn it into a date with [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior), then use [`date.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) to turn it back into a string.

Always attempt to work with dates as dates, not as strings. Ideally turning them into dates as early as you can and not going back to strings until you absolutely have to.